# Heroku Worker Dyno memcachem

Tags: node.js, heroku, memcached, memcachier

I have a Heroku App using 3 dynos: 1 web and 2 worker dynos.
For inter-dyno-communication I choose memcachier, everthing is implemented using nodejs.

The Web-Dyno has no problems connecting to the memcacher service and works like a charme, but trying to connect with a worker dyno fails and the TCP connection receives a reset:

```
MemJS: Server <mc5.dev.ec2.memcachier.com:11211> failed after (2) retries with error - write ECONNRESET
```

The method I am connecting to the service is the same that already works in the Web-Dyno..

Where is the problem?

This Code:

```
    var MemJS = require('memjs').Client,
        memjs = MemJS.create();

    setInterval(function () {
     memjs.set('test', 'test'); 

     memjs.get('test', function (err, buf) {
         if (err)
             console.log('ERROR with the damn memcache service ' + err);
         else
             console.log('Memcache service working: ' + buf.toString());
     });
    }, 5000);
```

Works on the web-dyno but doesn't work on the worker-dyno..